# How to select any date on datepicker in webdriverIO typescript

Tags: typescript, datepicker, cucumber, mocha.js, webdriver-io

I would like assistance on creating a webdriver.io typescript for this, i would like to select any date on this by clicking any of the date on the current month, your assistance is greatly appreciated

[image]

```
<div data-randomd917s2ad class="the-calendar-container">
    <div data-randomd917s2ad class="dropdown-calendar-show">
        <!---->
        <div data-randomd917s2ad class="the-calendar-table">
        <table data-randomx0123ab data-irandomeb9232 class="calendartable-condensed">
            <thead data-randomx0123ab>...</thead>
            <tbody data-randomx0123ab>
                <tr data-randomx0123ab>...</tr>
                <tr data-randomx0123ab>
                    <!---->
                    <td data-randomx0123ab data-date="2023-03-27" class="lastmonth"> 27 </td>
                    <td data-randomx0123ab data-date="2023-03-28" class="lastmonth"> 28 </td>
                    <td data-randomx0123ab data-date="2023-03-29" class="lastmonth"> 29 </td>
                    <td data-randomx0123ab data-date="2023-03-30" class="lastmonth"> 30 </td>
                    <td data-randomx0123ab data-date="2023-03-31" class="lastmonth"> 31 </td>
                    <td data-randomx0123ab data-date="2023-04-01" class="weekend"> 1 </td>
                    <td data-randomx0123ab data-date="2023-04-02" class="weekend"> 2 </td>
                </tr>
                <tr data-randomx0123ab>
                <!---->
                    <td data-randomx0123ab data-date="2023-04-03" class> 3 </td>
                    <td data-randomx0123ab data-date="2023-04-04" class="currentactivedate"> 4 </td>
                    <td data-randomx0123ab data-date="2023-04-05" class> 5 </td>
                    <td data-randomx0123ab data-date="2023-04-06" class> 6 </td>
                    <td data-randomx0123ab data-date="2023-04-07" class> 7 </td>
                    <td data-randomx0123ab data-date="2023-04-08" class="weekend"> 8 </td>
                    <td data-randomx0123ab data-date="2023-04-09" class="weekend"> 9 </td>
                </tr>
                <tr data-randomx0123ab>...</tr>
                <tr data-randomx0123ab>...</tr>
                <tr data-randomx0123ab>...</tr>
                <tr data-randomx0123ab>...</tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div data-randomd917s2ad class="calendar-time" style="display: none;">...</div>
  </div>
<!---->
  </div>
</div>
```

Suggested solutions are:

- unique element to check is the data-date attribute
- create three methods, selectDay, selectMonth, selectYear
- the year or month is selected by calculating how many months you need to go forward or backward in order to reach the year or month that is required
- the day is selected using the following:

  ```
  async selectDay(number) {
  await $(`[data-date^="${String(number).padStart(2, '0')}-"]`).waitForDisplayed();
  await $(`[data-date^="${String(number).padStart(2, '0')}-"]`).click();
  }
  ```
- this code that makes sure that 4 becomes 04

  ```
  String(number).padStart(2, '0')
  ```
- if you create an array of the months, you can match the current month by retrieving the text of the current month and using indexOf to be able to calculate how many months you should move to get to the required dat

Answer (score 0):

To select any date on the date picker widgets, u can use the below funtions take requires u to give element to bring the date picker and user required date.

trigger- webElement for date picker
date in formate = "mm-dd-yyyy"

````
function _datePicker(trigger,date){
    if(trigger===undefined || date===undefined){
        throw Error("Invalide parameters. Please provide both trigger element and expected date")
    }
    await trigger.click();
    let monthList=['January', "February","March","April"]
    let month=await $('give the locator of month');
    let year=await $('give locator of the year');
    let monthIndex=monthList.indexOf(month)+1;
    let tempDate=new Date(date);
    let userMonth=tempDate.getMonth()+1;
    let userYear=tempDate.getFullYear();
    if(year!==userYear){
        await $('give locator of month and year').click();
        await $('give locator fo the required year .ie findwithtext(year)').click()

    }
    let tempCount
    if(monthIndex>userMonth){
        tempCount=monthIndex-userMonth;
        while(tempCount!=0){
            await $('//button[@title="Previous month"]').click()
            await browser.pause(2000)
        }
    }else if(monthIndex<userMonth){
        tempCount=userMonth-monthIndex;
        while(tempCount!=0){
            await $('//button[@title="Next month"]').click()
            await browser.pause(2000)
        }
    }
    await $('//button[text()="'+tempDate.getDate()+'"]').click()
   

}```
````

Comment: you might want to make sure the function that you have above your code block is also wrapped in a codeblock. currently it's hard to read.

Comment: @Dean...Thanks am new here.